# Which slider plugin works fine, really fine, in IE8 & 9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow, carousel

I already have tried `bxslider`, and it causes jquery stops working.

But only in ie.

I really would thanks any help.

Comment: bxslider claims it supports IE7 and newer. You may be better off examining what exactly doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Pekka웃 is right. It says 'All modern versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS, Android, and Internet Explorer have been tested and are supported. IE8 and IE7 have been tested and work just fine.'

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using modernizr (if it applies) and a non-jQuery fallback.